# How can an unquoted metacharacter be part of a token?

Tags: bash

I was looking through the `bash` man page after reading through some of @Tim's questions about shell grammar, and I came up with a (simple) question of my own.

Here is an excerpt from `man bash` (see it yourself at `LESS=+/^DEFINITIONS man bash`:

```
   word   A  sequence  of  characters  considered  as a single unit by the
          shell.  Also known as a token.
   ...
   metacharacter
          A character that, when unquoted, separates words.   One  of  the
          following:
          |  & ; ( ) < > space tab
   control operator
          A token that performs a control function.  It is one of the fol-
          lowing symbols:
          || & && ; ;; ( ) | <newline>
```

But here's the circle I'm not getting:

- `;` is a "metacharacter."
- A "metacharacter", when unquoted, separates "words."
- "Token" is another term we can use for "word."
- `;;` is a token.
- Therefore `;;` is a word.

But, that means it's a word consisting of two word separators.  Given that it's unquoted and doesn't require blanks around it to be recognized (or does it??), how is this possible?

---

If your curious, the other questions about shell grammar I was reading through are these:

- [Bash's choice: operator vs reserved word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270738/135943)
- [Why don't word splitting and filename expansion apply to the conditional expression within `[[ ... ]]`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270298/135943)
- [Differences between keyword, reserved word, and builtin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267761/135943)

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the manpage. In general the parsing is done is such a way so that interpreting `;;` as a single token (SEMI_SEMI) has a higher precedence over interpreting it as two. If you're really curious about how it's done, it's all in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-44.5/bash/parse.y . My  mildly damaged brain doesn't find it to be a pleasant read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is using the same terminology as POSIX (no surprise).  Use that for comparison (and occasionally clarification).

Quoting from [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html)

> [3.113](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_113) ***Control Operator***
>
> In the shell command language, a token that performs a control function. It is one of the following symbols:

```
&   &&   (   )   ;   ;;   newline   |   ||
```

> The end-of-input indicator used internally by the shell is also considered a control operator.
>
> Note:
>       Token Recognition is defined in detail in XCU [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) .
>
> [3.407](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_407) ***Token***
>
> In the shell command language, a sequence of characters that the shell considers as a *single unit* when reading input. A token is either an operator or a word.
>
> Note:
>       The rules for reading input are defined in detail in XCU [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03).
>
> [3.440](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_440) ***Word***
>
> In the shell command language, a token other than an operator. In some cases a word is also a portion of a word token: in the various forms of parameter expansion, such as ${name-word}, and variable assignment, such as name=word, the word is the portion of the token depicted by word. The concept of a word is no longer applicable following word expansions-only fields remain.
>
> Note:
>       For further information, see XCU [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and [wordexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html).

So you see, there is a distinction between "word" and "token", and that they are not synonymous as implied in the question.  Moreover, the standard does not consider the two semicolons to be separate characters, but a *single unit*.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the other way around: "POSIX is using the same terminology as Bash (no surprise)". As POSIX builds on existing implementations (no surprise there also).

Comment: It say: "A token is either an operator or a word", or, again: "A token is ... a word", or, if you want to be more precise: "A word (is always) a token" (my words) confirmed by: "word:  a token other than an operator".

Comment: The distinction between "operator", "word" and "token" is crucial and that's what really answers it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` parses tokens that are generated by a lexical analyzer. When `bash` is breaking lines into words, it is probably using characters.  When it is parsing command syntax it is using tokens. In that instance, `;;` is not two ";" characters, rather, it is a token made up of two ";" (semi-colon) characters.  The lexical analyzer of bash reads the incoming character stream in a way that allows it to identify groups of characters as tokens.  So the code doesn't actually see semi-colons, it sees token codes.

See the `flex` and `bison` tools for a glimpse into this.  I don't believe bash uses these, but they are tools used for similar parsing applications and there is overview material into how parsing is typically done.

The [GNU Bash Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) is a good document to read.  Well-written, but a bit more explanatory than the man page.

Comment: Bash is actually one of the few widespread languages that does use bison.

Comment: @PSkocik: what most languages use?

Comment: @Tim Most common languages use hand-written parsers. Or so I heard. Being able to use yacc/bison is probably a good sign, as it implies your grammar has characteristics that make it parseable fast.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `;;` is a word. But it is not two metacharacters together.
It is the end of a case statement:

```
case a in 
    [a-z]) echo "yes" ;;
esac
```

Or one -liner:

```
case a in [a-z]) echo "yes" ;; esac
```

And, yes, it separated from the "yes" with an space, so it is a word.
It doesn't have to be though:

```
case a in [a-z]) echo "yes";; esac
```

Yes, the wording of very specific issues may be confusing sometimes.

Comment: You can take it further, actually: `case a in([a-z])echo "yes";;esac`